# Why do I need to use npm i tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat when i can just do npm i tailwind?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, tailwind-css

The [TailwindCSS getting started guide](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app) tells me to install itself using this command:

`npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9`

Why can't I just do:

`npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`

I don't understand why the long npm install name, what the @ symbol does and if the first command is even different to the second command. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the reason.

> Create React App doesn’t support PostCSS 8 yet so you need to install the Tailwind CSS v2.0 PostCSS 7 compatibility build for now

What you are installing is a special compatibility build to work with CRA.

Regarding what @npm means see
[https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#:~:text=is%20not%20valid.-,npm%20install%20%3Calias%3E%40npm%3A%3Cname%3E,-%3A](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install#:%7E:text=is%20not%20valid.-,npm%20install%20%3Calias%3E%40npm%3A%3Cname%3E,-%3A)

> Install a package under a custom alias.

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat. It is the package you are installing by the name `tailwindcss`

Comment: How can i use tailwindcss v3 by using @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat