# react rollup no styling with tailwind css and css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, rollup

I want to build a npm package with rollup but the styling is not available. I want to use style with tailwindcss, css or scss.
I created a repo with demo code to demonstrate this issue.
You can do the steps in README.md and then you will see that the styling is not applied
[Repo](https://github.com/guitar9/rollup-no-stlye)

This is my rollup.config.js

```
import babel from "@rollup/plugin-babel";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import commonjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import sourcemaps from "rollup-plugin-sourcemaps";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";

const input = "src/index.jsx";

var MODE = [
  {
    fomart: "es",
  },
];

var config = [];

MODE.map((m) => {
  var conf = {
    input: input,
    output: {
      dir: `dist`,
      format: m.fomart,
      sourcemap: true,
    },

    inlineDynamicImports: true,
    plugins: [
      replace({
        "process.env.NODE_ENV": JSON.stringify("development"),
      }),
      nodeResolve({
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
      }),
      postcss({
        minimize: true,
        modules: true,

        extract: true,
      }),

      json(),
      image(),
      babel({
        exclude: "node_modules/**",
        plugins: ["@babel/transform-runtime"],
        babelHelpers: "runtime",
      }),
      commonjs({
        include: "node_modules/**",
      }),
      sourcemaps(),
    ],
  };
  config.push(conf);
});

export default [...config];
```

Comment: I tried tackling this but it has too large a scope, sorry. I leave you a few hints hoping they help you. The global styles (like bootstrap) aren't working because you are using CSS modules in your postcss config (which prefixes the styles, check the dist/index.css and look for "bootstrap-min"), remove the `modules: true` line and you're good. About the tailwind config I suspect that you need some kind of config or plugin, like explained in https://samrobbins.uk/blog/tailwind-component-library#:~:text=postcss%40%5E7%20autoprefixer%40%5E9-,and%20create%20a%20simple,-postcss.config.js

Comment: thank you very much :) the bootstrap style is now there but with tailwind is does not worked. I followed the steps at the blog

Comment: now it works. I had to change purge: ["./src/**/*.js"] to purge: ["./src/**/*.jsx"].
@yuriy636  I would give you the bounty when you are making a answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bootstrap styles aren't working because of the PostCSS "modules" option in rollup config. This option prefixes the class names (you can see it in `dist/index.css` generated file, by looking for "bootstrap-min") in order to avoid conflicts, but in our case we want Bootstrap styles to be global.

```js
postcss({
  minimize: true,
  modules: true, // <--- this line

  extract: true,
}),
```

by removing it, the Bootstrap CSS is generated without any CSS module prefix.

Regarding Tailwind, you have to install the [compatibility build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187389/why-do-i-need-to-use-npm-i-tailwindcssnpmtailwindcss-postcss7-compat-when-i-c) of Tailwind and configure its PostCSS plugin in the rollup config, like described in https://samrobbins.uk/blog/tailwind-component-library